# sending mail in outlook with text,attachment and html using python not working

Tags: python, email, mime

I want to send mail using python with attachment,mail body as text and html .My code is working fine if we open the mail via `gmail.com` but if we open it via `outlook` client it is not rendering properly.If I attach the text message with `MIMEMultipart("mixed")` the html is not rendered and if I attach the text with `MIMEMultipart("alternative")` the text is not displayed.My codebse is below:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def send_mail(fromaddr, toaddr, attachment, file_name,  html):

# instance of MIMEMultipart
msg = MIMEMultipart("mixed")

# storing the senders email address
msg['From'] = fromaddr

# storing the receivers email address
# msg['To'] = ', '.join(toaddr)
msg['To'] = toaddr


# storing the subject
msg['Subject'] = "Testing email functionality"

# string to store the body of the mail
body = "Please find the attachment"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8'))
# attach the body with the msg instance

relatedBody = MIMEMultipart("related")

messageBody = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

# messageBody.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8'))
messageBody.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8'))

relatedBody.attach(messageBody)

msg.attach(relatedBody)
# open the file to be sent
filename = file_name
attachment = open(attachment, "rb")

# instance of MIMEBase and named as p
p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

# To change the payload into encoded form
p.set_payload((attachment).read())

# encode into base64
encoders.encode_base64(p)

p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

# attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg'
msg.attach(p)

# creates SMTP session
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

# start TLS for security
s.starttls()

# Authentication
s.login("sender_mail_id", "sender_password")

# Converts the Multipart msg into a string
text = msg.as_string()

# sending the mail
s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

# terminating the session
s.quit()
```

Please help me to working with it properly.

Comment: Have you tried to export any Outlook email to see how it should be constructed?

Comment: No idea how to do that..It'll be helpful if you suggest the way